# "The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed" after upgrading to Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

When I try to login in to the frontend, as a customer, I get this error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.
Line: 1052
```

I've read about other people running into the same issue [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116), with the solution being [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11116#issuecomment-332864555).

I've never worked with reference blocks so I am unsure if they mean that I need to edit any of the Magento files or is the problem in my extensions?

**EDIT**

Found this in one of my extension layout files:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top" ifconfig="cancelorder/general/active" template="CancelOrder::recent.phtml">
```

Could this be whats causing the error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes that's most probably it.
This is the intended behavior:
You can use `ifconfig` attributes only on `block`, `ui_component`, `action`.
`referenceBlock` does not allow this attribute.
The `xsd` section that describes `referenceBlock` can be found in `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd`.

```
<xs:complexType name="blockReferenceType" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="action" type="actionType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                    Argument name must be unique in scope of action.
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:key name="blockReferenceActionArgumentName">
                <xs:selector xpath="argument"></xs:selector>
                <xs:field xpath="@name"></xs:field>
            </xs:key>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="arguments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="block" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="container" type="containerType" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="referenceBlock" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element ref="referenceContainer" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="uiComponent" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute type="elementNameType" name="name" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="template" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="display" default="true" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="remove" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Nothing about `ifconfig` in there.

You can try a different approach to solve your issue.
I assume that you are using `<referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top"` to add a block or execute an action on the specified block.
You can add the `ifconfig` attribute on your block or action tags.

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="cancelorder/general/active">
        <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">CancelOrder::recent.phtml</argument>
    </action>
    <!-- or -->
    <block class="..." ifconfig="cancelorder/general/active">...</block>
</referenceBlock>
```