# Trying to add date picker to widget admin config

Tags: magento2

**I have this code in `widget.xml`**

```
<parameter name="from_date" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="true"
                   source_model="BSS\BestSelling\Model\Config\Source\DatePicker">
            <label translate="true">From Date</label>
        </parameter>
```

**And this is my source model**

```
<?php
namespace BSS\BestSelling\Block;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;

class DatePicker extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    /**
     * @var  Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param Context  $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array    $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        //get configuration element
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        //check datepicker set or not
        if (!$this->_coreRegistry->registry('datepicker_loaded')) {
            $this->_coreRegistry->registry('datepicker_loaded', 1);
        }
        //add icon on datepicker
        $html .= '<button type="button" style="display:none;" class="ui-datepicker-trigger '
            .'v-middle"><span>Select Date</span></button>';
        // add datepicker with element by jquery
        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery", "jquery/ui"], function (jq) {
                jq(document).ready(function () {
                    jq("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '").datepicker( { dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" } );
                    jq(".ui-datepicker-trigger").removeAttr("style");
                    jq(".ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(){
                        jq("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '").focus();
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        // return datepicker element
        return $html;
    }
}
```

**But some how I am keep getting this error**

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): 
Invalid XML in file E:/BSS/Xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/BSS/BestSelling/etc/widget.xml:
Element 'parameter', attribute 'source_model': The attribute 'source_model' is not allowed.
```

Any tips?

Comment: add your code in \BSS\BestSelling\Model\Config\Source\DatePicker.php

Comment: the DatePicker.php already in correct folder

Comment: The error is straight forward. Its saying the attribute  `source_model` is not allowed in the parameter node of the `widget.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your BSS extension. My guess is your BSS extension version doesn't support your Magento version.

I also had the same problem with BSS when we moved to Magento 2.2.

(I'm assuming BSS stands for bsscommerce in your question)

**Alternatively** you can read this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/213444/51693) on whats wrong and how to fix it.