# Magento2 checkout break after migration. The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.

Tags: magento2, php

After migrating Magento. I have error only in checkout and checkout\cart **Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.**  exception
in    /magento-root/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(116).

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213424/the-attribute-ifconfig-is-not-allowed-after-upgrading-to-magento-2-2#answer-213444

Answer (score 0):

Check if any of your modules has the attribute *ifconfig* inside element *referenceBlock* you can look in `checkout_index_index.xml` or `checkout_cart_index.xml` files.